# Specifying a new source for the image tag at runtime in Javascript , jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change the src of a image at runtime using jQuery. I have created a fiddle. I am trying to load the image specified in the variable $newsrc when the button is clicked. I am not sure as to what should be specified an argument function changeImage(). I do not want to use anonymous function.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/KMFj2/5/

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add fiddle. I have edited and added it.

Comment: want to something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/KMFj2/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMFj2/7/)

Comment: Please update your answer such that the Q and A can be read and understood in the thread. It's better to copy a (small) piece of code here that explains what you did and why you did it. Now it's unfortunately impossible for others to read and understand the solution...

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
   $("#myimg").attr('src', "/myNEWimage.jpg");
```

where ofcourse you get the path specified from somewhere in a variable

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KMFj2/13/ - Note the change in when the jquery is loaded (didn't work with the previous setting - should resemble real world use though)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#image_id').click(function() {
     $(this).attr('src', "/new_image.jpg");
});
```